# How to make a google plus post with api request in IOS?

Tags: ios, google-plus

how to make a google plus post with api request?
I'm using GooglePlus.framework but the dialog should not appear when sharing

Answer (score 0):

I believe  you actually have the library working correctly. The dialog appears because a user must consent to share before content appears in the Google+ activity stream.

What you're trying to do is a frequently requested feature, please [star the issue tracker here](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=41&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Component%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) and suggest the best way to make writing to a user's activity stream awesome.